# memory management related system calls fro copy command in linux

Tags: system-calls

```
 strace cp reg.txt new.txt
```

for the above command how can i determine which system calls are related to memory management?
i know a few basic ones like map, mmap. the output has system calls like

```
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb78b3000
mmap2(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb76a5000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0x2a1) = 0xb78b4000
```

but is there a way to determine all of system calls related to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
strace -e trace=mmap,mmap2 cp reg.txt new.txt
```

to grep only memory related traces.